# Collectionview cell for row at index path not getting called for subsequent sections if the current section cell height is zero

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I came across an issue in collection view in our project -

1. Collectionview consist of 4 sections. Each section consist of 1 cell.
2. If we keep height zero for a collection view cell in section 0, cellforrrowatindexpath will not be called for section zero. The problem we are facing is cellforrowatindexapath will not be called for subsequent sections as well. Collection view will not display anything on the screen though other section cells heights are provided.

Updated:

```
 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
       return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1 
    }


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      Switch indexpath.section {
     case 0: return  CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 0)
         case 1:  return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
         case 2: return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)
      }
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 Switch indexpath.section {
     case 0: return A()
         case 1: return B()
         case 2: return C()
      }
}
```

If anyone has better understanding of why collection view works in this way please let me know.

Comment: Please edit you answer to add the relevant collectionView methods.

Comment: added relavant methods

Comment: Does your view controller conform to UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Answer (score 2):

If you use storyboard, try to change Collection View's `Estimate Size` to **None** in Size Inspector section.

Please check:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This might be the correct answer, since I was unable to reproduce the problem - the cells were visible until I changed the Estimated Size to None, than they disappeared. Same when setting this value programatically:
`(self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)` did the trick and setting it to `CGSize.zero` made it broken again.

Comment: Collectionview estimated size is none only in the storyboard. Setting (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.estimatedItemSize programmatically will make size to calculate from auto layout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once. It might be resolved by returning CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude or 0.1, instead of 0.

Comment: We tried using CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude, unfortunately it didn't work.  It works fine if we return 0.1 height. Could you please elaborate the reason behind that collection view behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    if let fl = theCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    }
```

Now `sizeForItemAt` and `cellForItemAt` will be called for your additional sections.